# Windows phone back button task preview

Tags: windows-phone-8

On the windows phone when you press and hold the back button a collection of tiles will appear that represent apps that were recently run or are running in the background. Generally the tiles will show a preview of the app in the visual state it was in when it last navigated away from. I have seen some apps however that will show their logo on this tile regardless of the state the app was in when navigated away from. I have been beating my head against the internet trying to find how this is done. Perhaps I am missing the proper terms to search for in order point myself in the correct direction. Does anyone know how to accomplish swapping the back button history preview image or perhaps help me find the correct search terms to locate help on this?

Comment: What apps have you seen that do this? There is no built-in feature to perform this action.

Comment: Just an idea... you get notified that the app will go to "sleep" and in that situation you could show that logo covering the whole page. My assumption would be, that Microsoft takes the screenshot somewhen after you got notified. But I never tested this and I have not seen an app that works as you described.